# Regex to select field with many numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this field

> *ET,358155100113030,HB,A,120a10,090b05,80d5dd77,81ac538b,2b65,8340,00400000,20,100,0000,344f,799#

I want a SQL to read all fields whith

> *ET,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,HB

This is DDL of table

```
CREATE TABLE `comandorecebidoe3` (
  `Id` CHAR(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Command` VARCHAR(200) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `DateInclude` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`Id`),
  KEY `Index 2` USING BTREE (`DateInclude`),
  KEY `comandorecebidoe3_idx1` USING BTREE (`Command`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
;
```

This field is Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE Command REGEXP '^*ET,[^,]*,HB'
```

To explain:

- `^` -- anchor at start
- `*ET,` -- demand that these characters be there
- `[^,]` -- match anything except `,`
- `[^,]*` -- match anything except `,` -- for any number of times
- `,HB` -- demand these exist

If you need that field to be exactly 15 characters long, then use `[^,]{15}`.  (There are other variants.)